# Simple JavaScript append array link ids to html doc?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of hypothetical JavaScript link ids  `myArray = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];` 
How do I create each link element and append it to the html document?

Comment: as long as they wrk ;p

Comment: `$.each(myArray, function(_,x) {$('body').append('<a id="'+x+'"></a>')});`

Comment: You need to explain a little more what output you're looking for... then you need to show what you've tried yourself.  Then, if that hasn't helped you solve it yourself, you'll probably get some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myArray = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];
var container = document.getElementById('container');
myArray.forEach(function(id){
  container.innerHTML =  container.innerHTML + "<a href=\""+id+"\">"+id+"</a>"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suwJr/