# Simple JavaScript bind onClick using array?

Tags: javascript

Here's my JS code:

```
var myArray = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];
var container = document.getElementById('container');
myArray.forEach(function(id){
  container.innerHTML =  container.innerHTML + "<a href=\""+id+"\">"+id+"</a>"
});
```

I want to bind an onClick Event handler to each link using an array, instead of repeating the code 3 times?

Comment: Are you trying to get people to do your work/homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253954/simple-javascript-append-array-link-ids-to-html-doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
function functionToCall(evt){
    console.log('You clicked the element with id = "' + this.id + '"');
}

var myArray = ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
    container = document.getElementById('container'),
    // creating a new 'a' element:
    link = document.createElement('a'),
    // initialising an empty variable:
    temp;

myArray.forEach(function(id){
    // copying the created 'a' element
    temp = link.cloneNode();

    // assigning it a href attribute:
    temp.href = '#' + id;

    // giving an id:
    temp.id = 'link_' + id;

    // appending a textNode to that copied 'a' element:
    temp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(id));

    // assigning the event-handler (assuming you wanted a click-handler):
    temp.addEventListener('click', functionToCall);

    // appending the copied 'a' element to the container Node:
    container.appendChild(temp);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cxF7a/1/).

Comment: Now I can study your code :) Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help.